# Creating a strong password with Yup and Formik with individual error messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

### What I have

I'm trying to create a password field which validates the strength of the input, in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604455/8582246) I found the `regex` I can use to validate if the input meets specific conditions, the problem with this approach is that it throws only one error message for each of the validations.

```js
password: yup
    .string()
    .required('Please Enter your password')
    .matches(
      /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/,
      "Must Contain 8 Characters, One Uppercase, One Lowercase, One Number and one special case Character"
    ),
```

### What i want

what I want is validate each of the characters that the user enters and throw the specific errors if each of the conditions are fulfilled, e.g if user inpunt is missing a lower case, it should throw the error 'must have a lower case', if the input is missing a number, it should throw the number 'must have a number' and so on. What I've tried it's to use match but this doesn't work:

```js
password: yup
    .string()
    .required('Please Enter your password')
    .matches(/^[a-z]+$/, 'One lowercase character')
    .matches(/^[A-Z]+$/, 'One uppercase character')
    .matches(/^\d+$/, 'One number')
    // ... other validation
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend a different password requirement. https://xkcd.com/936/ Convoluted, hard-to-remember but short passwords are probably the worst approach there is

Comment: understood, but I still want to know the approach to use to solve this kind of problems, individual regex validations with Yup and formik.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to remove `^` (matches the beginning of input) and `$` (matches the end of input) [assertions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#boundary-type_assertions) from your code, like so:

```
password: Yup.string()
  .required("Required")
  .min(8, "Must be 8 characters or more")
  .matches(/[a-z]+/, "One lowercase character")
  .matches(/[A-Z]+/, "One uppercase character")
  .matches(/[@$!%*#?&]+/, "One special character")
  .matches(/\d+/, "One number"),
```

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-formil-yup-password-validation-zxlp2?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: Nice one. ...I added more special characters to mine. Works great.